# Attached Cell that allows rotatable 3D plot (non-deployed?)

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I would like to use `AttachCell` to create popup looking window that attaches to the notebook and contains a 3D plot that I can rotate. The following works except I cannot rotate the plot.

```
AttachCell[EvaluationNotebook[],
 Grid[{
   {Button["Close", NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]; 
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[]], ImageSize -> All]},
   {Dynamic@Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 3}, ImageSize -> 600
      ]}},
  Frame -> True, Background -> White], Center, 0, Center]
```

It looks like the issue is that `AttachedCell` makes the plot "deployed".  I prefer using `AttachCell` over `PopupWindow` or `CreateDocument` as the former attaches to the notebook seamlessly (even if I move the notebook) and allows me to scroll in the background.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After messing with this for a bit... Wrapping in Style and setting Deployed->False works.

```
AttachCell[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  Style[Grid[{{Button["Close", NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]];
       SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[]], ImageSize -> All]}, {Dynamic@
       Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 3}, ImageSize -> 600]}}, 
    Frame -> True, Background -> White], Deployed -> False], Center, 
  0, Center];
```

Comment: Just in case you want to make this a bit nicer still: if you want the plot to just be rotatable but not editable or visibly selected I found the following set of options to be useful: `Deployed -> False, Selectable -> True, Editable -> False, 
ShowSelection -> False`